# Cannot resolve YouTubePlayerSupportFragment in transaction.add();

Tags: android

I want to add a youtube player in main activity also use with another fragment too.

YouTubePlayerFragment f = YouTubePlayerFragment.newInstance();

f.initialize("KEY",  this);

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.watch_video_player).commit();

Comment: it gives me error 
Inconvertible type cannot cast 'android.x.fragment.app.Fragment' to 'com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment'

Comment: finally, found the solution,
Ignore the error at:
**.replace(R.id.watch_video_player).commit();** and run the code

Answer (score 0):

You need to define fragment by it's class name

```
<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
    android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```